# Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Tags: json, gson

I am getting the following exception raised parsing some JSON content

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 73
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
    at jsonParseCommon.jsonParse(jsonParseCommon.java:136)
    at jsonParseCommon.jsonProcess(jsonParseCommon.java:88)
    at jsonMain.main(jsonMain.java:21)
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 73
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:531)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
    ... 4 more
```

I am using the parse(String) method because JSON content is coming from a field in a file, not only JSON content in the file

invocation looks like this

```
String      fragment;
JsonParser  parser;
JsonElement element;

parser = new JsonParser();
element = null;
try {
    element =  parser.parse(fragment);
    .
    .
    .
```

How do I follow message suggestion of JsonReader.setLenient(true) 
when the JsonReader is not surfaced to this string method?

Comment: Where do you get the data from? Couldn't you try fixing the malformed input instead of using a lenient parser?

Comment: it comes from an outside provider. trying to contact them about the issues and resolving, but would like to make progress in the mean time. maybe identify additional problems before they respond.